# Samsung Health Android SDK target SDK version

Tags: android, sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk, targetsdkversion, samsung-health

I'm developing an app which uses targetSdkVersion 27. We would like to integrate the Samsung Health Android SDK which has a targetSdkVersion support of 25.

Can this be done without problems?

Also the Play Store has a limit of min targetSDkVersion of 26 since this month. What does this mean regarding this? Will we able to upload the app into the Play Store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When building your project, Android Studio would merge the manifests of your libraries and your app. In the case of your libraries having a lower targetSDKVersion than your app, the app's version has higher priority and will override the library's.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge